# IMO 2016 Problem 5

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, contest-math, roots, recreational-mathematics

The equation
$$
(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\dots(x-2016)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\dots(x-2016)
$$
is written on a board, with $2016$ linear factors on each side. What is the least possible value of $k$ for which it is possible to erase exactly $k$ of these $4032$ factors so that at least one factor remains on each side and the resulting equation has no real solutions?

Comment: 2016 is now. When does/did the contest in question end?

Comment: @HenningMakholm it ended mid July. http://www.imo2016.org/

Comment: The IMO 2016 was in 6. - 16. July.

Comment: Clearly $k$ cannot be less than $2016$, since if the same factor $(x-p)$ was on both sides, the resulting equation would have solution $x=p$. For $k=2016$ I suppose it would be possible to erase $1008$ factors from each side if you do it very properly, although I would not assume the pattern is very obvious. Maybe if you erased the factors in groups of $63$, since that is the largest odd factor of $2016$.

Comment: @Batominovski: How is this combinatoircs?

Comment: @quid How is this not combinatorics?  This is pretty much a solitaire game.

Comment: @Batominovski strange argument. But alright keep your tag.

Comment: If you read Chinese: [solutions](http://www.zyymat.com/imo-2016-solutions.html). Google translator may help.

Comment: @A.G.  It looks like that solution is different from mine.  Would you mind writing it down (in English) here?

Comment: @Batominovski OK, I will try my best, but my Chinese is awful :-)

Answer (score 4):

An interpretation of the solution from [here](http://www.zyymat.com/imo-2016-solutions.html). Sorry my Chinese.

1. $k\ge 2016$ (see @McFry comment above).
2. For $t=1,2,\ldots,504$, remove the following (exactly $2016$ many) factors
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   & (x-(4t-2)),\quad (x-(4t-1)) &\qquad \text{ from the LHS},\\
   & (x-(4t-3)),\quad (x-4t) &\qquad \text{ from the RHS}. 
   \end{align*}
   $$
   We are to prove that what's left has no real solutions. It would mean that the smallest $k$ is $2016$. We are left with the equation
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   & (x-1)(x-4)(x-5)(x-8)\ldots(x-2013)(x-2016)=\\
   = & (x-2)(x-3)(x-6)(x-7)\ldots (x-2014)(x-2015). 
   \end{align*}\tag{1}
   $$
3. Let's prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   (x-1)(x-4)&<(x-2)(x-3),\\
   (x-5)(x-8)&<(x-6)(x-7)\qquad \text{etc.}\tag{2}
   \end{align*}
   $$
   In other words, we prove that for $t=1,\ldots,504$
   $$
   (x-(4t-3))(x-4t)<(x-(4t-2))(x-(4t-1)).\tag{3}
   $$
   Denote $y=x-4t$. Then "RHS minus LHS" in (3) is
   $$
   (y+2)(y+1)-(y+3)y=y^2+3y+2-y^2-3y=2>0.
   $$
   Hence (2) is proven for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
4. Obviously, $x\in \{1,2,\ldots,2016\}$ is not a solution
5. If $x<1$, $x>2016$ or $\exists m\colon 1\le m\le 503$ such that $4m<x<4m+1$ then all sides of the inequalities in (2) are positive, therefore, (1) has no real roots.
6. If $\exists n\colon 1\le n\le 504$ such that $4n-3<x<4n-2$ or $4n-1<x<4n$ then one inequality among first $n$ has negative LHS and positive RHS and the rest 503 inequalities have both sides positive. Then equality in (1) is again impossible.
7. What's left is to prove that $4n-2<x<4n-1$ for some $n$, $1\le n\le 504$, cannot be a solution to (1). In this case the following $503$ inequalities holds true (similar prove as above) with both sides being positive
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   (x-4)(x-5)&>(x-3)(x-6),\\
   (x-8)(x-9)&>(x-7)(x-10),\\
   &\vdots\\
   (x-2012)(x-2013)&>(x-2011)(x-2014).
   \end{align*}
   $$
   Moreover, for $1\le n\le 504$ we have $2\le 4n-2<x<4n-1\le 2015$, hence
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   (x-1)&>(x-2)&>0,\\
   -(x-2016)&>-(x-2015)&>0,
   \end{align*}
   $$
   which implies
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   & -(x-1)(x-4)(x-5)(x-8)\ldots(x-2013)(x-2016)>\\
   > & -(x-2)(x-3)(x-6)(x-7)\ldots (x-2014)(x-2015),
   \end{align*}
   $$
   so again (1) is impossible.

Comment: I understand that you don't know Chinese very well.  But are you sure that this is all there is in that solution?  Because quid seems to have a point now, as this does not look like a solution.  As $a>b$ and $c>d$ does not mean $ac>bd$.  (I'm not criticizing you, by the way.  Just wondering about the Chinese text.)  Thanks for the translation, by the way.

Comment: @Batominovski Yes, the solution says more, I will try to interpret it.

Comment: @Batominovski Hopefully, now it is right.

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks for the translation.  Much simpler than my solution.

Comment: Suppose I were to remove $(x−1)$ from $LHS$ and $(x−2)$ from $RHS$. Would that not produce an equation $x−2=x−1$ which has no real solutions using $k=2$? Be generous, I'm a novice

Answer (score 3):

**Continuing from Aaron's Now Deleted Good Hint**

Replace $2016$ by $4N$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$.  As stated by McFry, $k\geq 4N$.  I shall prove that $k=4N$ is possible.  On the left-hand side of the given equation, factors of the form $(x-j)$ with $j\equiv 0,1\pmod{4}$ are removed, and on the right-hand side of the equation, factors of the form $(x-j)$ with $j\equiv 2,3\pmod{4}$ are removed.  Then, we have to show that the polynomial functions
$$f(x):=\prod_{r=1}^{N}\,\big(x-(4r-3)\big)\,\big(x-4r\big)$$
and
$$g(x):=\prod_{r=1}^N\,\big(x-(4r-2)\big)\,\big(x-(4r-1)\big)$$
do not coincide on $\mathbb{R}$.  It is easy to see that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{r=1}^N\,\big(4r-2,4r-1)$.  We are left to show that $f(x)<g(x)$ also holds for $x\in(4s-2,4s-1)$ for all $s=1,2,\ldots,N$.

For all $r=1,2,\ldots,N$ and for $x\in(4s-2,4s-1)$ for a fixed $s=1,2,\ldots,N$, we have
$$\lambda_r(x):=\frac{\big(x-(4r-3)\big)\,\big(x-4r\big)}{\big(x-(4r-2)\big)\,\big(x-(4r-1)\big)}=1-\frac{2}{\big(x-(4r-2)\big)\,\big(x-(4r-1)\big)}\,.$$
Thus, by AM-GM, we have
$$\lambda_s(x)\geq 1+\frac{2}{\big((4s-1)-x\big)\big(x-(4s-2)\big)}\geq 1+\frac{2}{1/4}=9\,.$$
Now,
$$\prod_{r=1}^{s-1}\,\lambda_r(x)\geq 1-\sum_{r=1}^{s-1}\,\frac{2}{\big(x-(4r-2)\big)\,\big(x-(4r-1)\big)}>1-\sum_{r=1}^{s-1}\,\frac{2}{4(s-r)\big(4(s-r)+1\big)}\,.$$
Hence,
$$\prod_{r=1}^{s-1}\,\lambda_r(x)> 1-\frac{1}{8}\,\sum_{r=1}^{s-1}\,\frac{1}{(s-r)^2}>\frac{7}{8}-\frac{1}{8}\,\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=\frac{7}{8}-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{3}{4}\,.$$
Also,
$$\prod_{r=s+1}^N\,\lambda_r(x)\geq 1-\sum_{r=s+1}^{N}\,\frac{2}{\big(x-(4r-2)\big)\,\big(x-(4r-1)\big)}>1-\sum_{r=s+1}^{N}\,\frac{2}{4(r-s)\big(4(r-s)-1\big)}\,.$$
Ergo,
$$\prod_{r=s+1}^{N}\,\lambda_r(x)> 1-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\,\sum_{r=s+2}^{N}\,\frac{1}{(r-s)(r-s-1)}>\frac{5}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\,\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=\frac{5}{6}-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{17}{24}\,.$$
Hence,
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\prod_{r=1}^N\,\lambda_r(x)>\frac{3}{4}\cdot 9\cdot \frac{17}{24}>4>1\,.$$
As $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both negative, it follows that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in(4s-2,4s-1)$ with $s=1,2,\ldots,N$.  The proof is now complete.

Comment: Yes, I also feel Aaron's hint should not have been deleted.  That hint (and the discussion in its comments) contribute value to the problem and its solution.